# Is there any way in C++ to refer to a function template while neither calling it nor supplying its template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Here's the code I would like to work:

```
template <class T> void Foo(T&& param);

template <class F> void CallMe(F&& func)
{
    func(42);
}

int main()
{
    CallMe(Foo);
}
```

The compiler chokes when it tries to instantiate `CallMe` because it doesn't know what I mean by `Foo`.  It works if I write `Foo<int>` of course, but I'd like to avoid that because in the real code the template parameters can be complex.

My current workaround is to use callable objects instead of free functions.  For example:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    template <class T> void operator()(T&&);
};
```

This works fine, but I'm sure it will confuse users of my library.  Is there some template magic I can use to make the first version work?

Comment: template functions are recipes for creating functions. They aren't functions themselves. Since they are only recipes, there is no way to know which of an infinite possible number of instantiated functions one could refer to.

Comment: This can work, in principle.  In fact, functional languages like F# do work this way.  If only the compiler would "hold off" a little bit, it could see my call to `func` and deduce that it needs to instantiate `Foo<int>`.  I'm wondering if there's some way I could trick it into doing that.

Comment: You can use the address of a template function as soon as you apply template arguments. This results effectively in the instancing of this template function. You can use the address of a template function in another template applying its template arguments. This results in instancing of this template function with the other template as soon as that is instanced. As already mentioned by @doug, without template arguments, it's not possible. Whatever F# or other functional languages do, this is not what happens in C++.

Comment: What do you expect should `CallMe()` do, if neither `CallMe()` nor `Foo()` has a concrete type? Please, note that template functions may deduce its concrete type from a call with arguments of concrete types. (Again, this results in instancing of this template function.) However, this is not true for class templates.

Comment: @PeterRuderman -  your "workaround" is the solution in this case (assuming your `main()` does `CallMe(Foo())` to pass an object, not a type). In C++, the call point  (the statement in `main()` in your case) needs to provide all information needed so the compiler can deduce the type.  The compiler does not "hold off" in the way you wish - doing so would interact badly with a bunch of other language features (e.g. separate compilation model, extern templates in C++11, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some template magic I can use to make the first version work?

I wish. And I hope someday. There have been several proposals in this area (e.g. [P0119](https://wg21.link/p0119) and [P0834](https://wg21.link/p0834)). Until then, the best you can do is write a lifting macro to turn your *name* into a function object that calls that name:

```
#define FWD(...) std::forward<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>(__VA_ARGS__)
#define LIFT(name) [&](auto&&... args)     \
    noexcept(noexcept(name(FWD(args)...))) \
    -> decltype(name(FWD(args)...))        \
    { return name(FWD(args)...); }
```

This lets you write:

```
CallMe(LIFT(Foo));
```

which otherwise does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links.  Those are an interesting read.

Comment: Is `[&]` the right thing to do in `LIFT`?  Seems ... dangerous to hide an implicit capture like that.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I dunno. Let's me write `LIFT(obj.foo)` in a way that works and doesn't copy `obj`. I don't really use this in places where I would need the copy.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make something that somewhat resembles the code in the question, but not exactly.

A function call:

```
int main()
{
    CallMe(Foo);
}
```

expects an object as a parameter. The object can be a function pointer, a class instance, a lambda, or something similar. It can't be an uninstantiated template function, since it is not an object. Only an instantiated function is an object.

As the original question states, using function-like objects is a work-around, and assumes that the following is too confusing for some users:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    template <class T> void operator()(T&&);
};
```

Instead of that, it is possible to use a generic lambda, which is basically the same, but without all the boiler plate. A generic lambda looks almost like a regular function:

```
auto Foo = [](auto x) 
{ 
   std::cout << x << '\n';
};
int main()
{
   CallMe(Foo);
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'm not sure if this works for me or not.  I'll play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some template magic I can use to make the first version work?

No.

The name of a function template don’t name a function type but a family of them. If it were possible, and the type of `func` would be deduced from `Foo` the type of `T` will remain non-deduced which is needed in order to instantiate the `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... ) )
```

then

```
CallMe(OVERLOADS_OF(Foo));
```

creates a function object that represents the overloads of the name `Foo`, which include the functions produced by your template function named `Foo`.

`RETURNS` is also useful in other contexts.  [@Barry has a proposal](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0573r1.html) to make `RETURNS(X)` be similar to `=> X`, at least for lambdas.