# How to create a function object that calls a specific function

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have a function template that accepts arbitrary function object as an argument:

```
template<typename F>
// func is a function object
void do_something(F func) {
    // Do something with func
}
```

I also have an ordinary function:

```
int f(int x) {
    return 2 * x;
}
```

And I want to pass `f` as an argument to `do_something`. However, when I do it, `do_something` is instantiated with `F = int (*)(int)`, and calls to `func` inside `do_something` result in run-time indirection through function pointer. What I want is to instantiate `do_something` specifically to call `f`, rather than any function with the same signature. I could achieve this with a lambda expression:

```
do_something([](int x) -> int { return f(x); });
```

In this case, `do_something` will be instantiated with `F` being a new closure type, and no pointer indirection will happen at run time. But this code doesn't look good. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest you profile your code. First of all, `do_something(f)` may be inlined. If it isn't, then you'll get an idea of whether it's actually worth it to make it more complicated just to shave off a few function pointer indirections. And if it really is worth it, then why not go with the lambda?

Comment: This will all be optimized out by a good compiler.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675813/is-there-any-way-in-c-to-refer-to-a-template-function-while-neither-calling-it.  The `LIFT` macro described in the accepted answer here is a decent compromise.